# How to set Android Chronometer base time from Date object?

Tags: android, chronometer

I've got an issue with starting chronometer from the specific time.
There is a Date object I want my chronometer start from:

```
Date d = new Date(); //now, just for example
chronometer.setBase(d.getTime()); //long value of d
Log.d("Date: " , "d.getTime() time is [" + d.getTime() +"]");
Log.d("Chron: " , "chronometer.getBase() is [" + chronometer.getBase() +"]");
//let's print out elapsedRealtime from official sample
Log.d("Chron: " , "SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() is [" + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +"]");
```

Output:

```
06-02 13:35:23.025: D/Date:(928): d.getTime() time is [1338644123032]
06-02 13:35:23.037: D/Chron:(928): chronometer.getBase() is [1338644123032]
06-02 13:35:23.037: D/Chron:(928): SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() is [11624388]
```

Actually, why this long values of time differes (11624388 and 1338644123032)?

When I start my chronometer from base

```
chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
```

- it always works fine ( "00:00" and rising)

But when I try to set the date from a past Date (f.e. yesterday):

```
chronometer.setBase(yesterday.getTime());
```

- it shows "00:0(" and changes every second the latest char to ")", "*", "/" and others

Could you please advise how can I set the chronometer base to a Date object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Actually, why this long values of time differes (11624388 and 1338644123032)?

`SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` is the number of milliseconds since the device was turned on. The other values are based off of `System.currentTimeMillis()`, the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.

> Could you please advise how can I set the chronometer base to a Date object?

You don't. That is not what `Chronometer` is for. Quoting [the documentation for `Chronometer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html):

> You can give it a start time in the elapsedRealtime() timebase, and it counts up from that, or if you don't give it a base time, it will use the time at which you call start().

Comment: Thanks Mark. My goal is to create a digital clock which shows time duration between two activities (stored in database with time record). Could you please advise the best practice for this?

Comment: @Vitalliuss: If both your start and end times are fixed in a database, then just use `TextView`, since your value will not be changing. If your start time is fixed in a database, and you are counting from there, you will need to create your own `Chronometer` equivalent that takes a start time in the `System.currentTimeMillis()` timebase, instead of `elapsedRealtime()`. Since [`Chronometer` is not a very long class](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/Chronometer.java), cloning it and making your own should be reasonably easy.

Answer (score 35):

I actually had a similar problem (the Date was coming from an external service, not the database) and I wanted to show how old the date was.

It proved to be simple:

```
long lastSuccess = serviceDate.getTime(); //Some Date object
long elapsedRealtimeOffset = System.currentTimeMillis() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
pollAgeView.setBase(lastSuccess - elapsedRealtimeOffset);
pollAgeView.start();
```

Comment: This is a much more reasonable approach than rewriting `Chronometer` to accept a `Date` and answers the question better than the current accepted answer.

Comment: This is not a good ideia, since user could change the date from your device. So how you sincronize a real date time from server without using system base time ?